# Create dynamic object based on array element: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Yeh..I know its not that much related to technical. Its absolutely logical But I'm stuck here.

Lets consider i have an array **1)** `arr = ['bno', 'am', 'recruiter'];`

**Expected Output**

```
Obj = {
     key_name: 'bno',
     emplist = [],
     children_obj: {
        key_name: 'am',
        emplist = [],
        children_obj: {
          key_name: 'recruiter',
          emplist = [],
        }
     }
```

};

**2)**
`arr = ['am', 'recruiter'];`

**Output**

```
Obj = {
         key_name: 'am',
         emplist = [],
         children_obj: {
            key_name: 'recruiter',
            emplist = [],
         }
   };
```

Anybody can please suggest or provide best way to create such dynamic object based on array element. Would help me out to get it.

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Next time, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/mazofegejo/2/edit?html,js,console try this and watch in console

Comment: It's easy with a short, recursive function: https://jsfiddle.net/xp3zazmo/ Or a non-mutating version: https://jsfiddle.net/xp3zazmo/1/

Comment: @Cerbrus: Noted

Comment: Here's one that uses a rest parameter to separate the head of the list from the tail. https://jsfiddle.net/xp3zazmo/2/